# How can I write a regex to order the paths of which I want to list them in numeric order

Tags: r, regex

I have hundreds of .wav files and imported them using list.files. Something like above:

```
  [1] "10/Project_English-10/BL-0001_A-conifer-cone-contains-seeds/Balsam-poplar-English-0701.wav"           
  [2] "10/Project_English-10/BL-0001_A-conifer-cone-contains-seeds/Birch-English-0700.wav"                   
  [3] "10/Project_English-10/BL-0001_A-conifer-cone-contains-seeds/Blueberry-English-0703.wav"  
.......
  [73] "3/Project_English-3/BL-0002_Lesser-horseshoe-bat/Capercaillie-English-0069.wav"                       
  [74] "3/Project_English-3/BL-0002_Lesser-horseshoe-bat/Fat-tail-scorpion-English-0082.wav"                  
  [75] "3/Project_English-3/BL-0002_Lesser-horseshoe-bat/Fire-salamander-English-0067.wav"
```

I use the following code to reorder the file paths of which I want number in each subpath follows numberic order. I have tried the following

```
filename<- file_list[order(as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(file_list,"[0-9]+(.*?)")) )]
```

The result is something like:

```
  [1] "3/Project_English-3/BL-0002_Lesser-horseshoe-bat/Capercaillie-English-0069.wav"                       
  [2] "3/Project_English-3/BL-0002_Lesser-horseshoe-bat/Fat-tail-scorpion-English-0082.wav"                  
  [3] "3/Project_English-3/BL-0002_Lesser-horseshoe-bat/Fire-salamander-English-0067.wav"
.......
  [73] "10/Project_English-10/BL-0001_A-conifer-cone-contains-seeds/Balsam-poplar-English-0701.wav"           
  [74] "10/Project_English-10/BL-0001_A-conifer-cone-contains-seeds/Birch-English-0700.wav"                   
  [75] "10/Project_English-10/BL-0001_A-conifer-cone-contains-seeds/Blueberry-English-0703.wav"
```

I also want the last subpath follows in numberic order, e.g. English-0067;English-0069. I tried to repeat the matching for the last subpath, but it will disorder the previous order followed by 3...10. How could I let all the numbers in the subpaths follows numberic order?

Comment: `(.*?)` at the end of a pattern never matches anything, it is useless.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to add /$ in the code

Comment: Non-essential to add ```(.*?)```  if only need to reoder the paths base on the first(few) numbers since ```stringr::str_extract``` would only catch the first match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```r
vec <- c( "10/Project_English-10/BL-0001_A-conifer-cone-contains-seeds/Balsam-poplar-English-0701.wav",
"10/Project_English-10/BL-0001_A-conifer-cone-contains-seeds/Birch-English-0700.wav",
"10/Project_English-10/BL-0001_A-conifer-cone-contains-seeds/Blueberry-English-0703.wav",
"3/Project_English-3/BL-0002_Lesser-horseshoe-bat/Capercaillie-English-0069.wav",
"3/Project_English-3/BL-0002_Lesser-horseshoe-bat/Fat-tail-scorpion-English-0082.wav",
"3/Project_English-3/BL-0002_Lesser-horseshoe-bat/Fire-salamander-English-0067.wav")
nums <- strcapture("^([0-9]+).*\\b([0-9]+)\\.[a-z]+$", vec, proto=list(a=0L,b=0L))
nums
#    a   b
# 1 10 701
# 2 10 700
# 3 10 703
# 4  3  69
# 5  3  82
# 6  3  67
do.call(order, nums)
# [1] 6 4 5 2 1 3
vec[do.call(order, nums)]
# [1] "3/Project_English-3/BL-0002_Lesser-horseshoe-bat/Fire-salamander-English-0067.wav"         
# [2] "3/Project_English-3/BL-0002_Lesser-horseshoe-bat/Capercaillie-English-0069.wav"            
# [3] "3/Project_English-3/BL-0002_Lesser-horseshoe-bat/Fat-tail-scorpion-English-0082.wav"       
# [4] "10/Project_English-10/BL-0001_A-conifer-cone-contains-seeds/Birch-English-0700.wav"        
# [5] "10/Project_English-10/BL-0001_A-conifer-cone-contains-seeds/Balsam-poplar-English-0701.wav"
# [6] "10/Project_English-10/BL-0001_A-conifer-cone-contains-seeds/Blueberry-English-0703.wav"
```

If you needed to also include the `BL-0001` in your ordering, all it would take is a small addition to the regex, an additional entry in `proto=`, and that's it. The use of `do.call(order, nums)` will handle 1 or more columns, regardless of how many.

Note that if you over-tune your regex, rows that don't match both groups here will return `NA` for both; this means it'll sort the `NA` rows last. If you find that one or more filenames are misordered, check the regex and the intermediate `nums` entries for those filenames.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Good to know that "\" escape the characters and "\b" delimit the word boundary(in this case it is numbers). One more question: since I am not very familiar with regex syntax, I wonder why there is no another "b" after "\\" in the ("^([0-9]+).*\\b([0-9]+)\\.[a-z]+$"(In other words, ("^([0-9]+).*\\b([0-9]+)\\b.[a-z]+$" or ("^([0-9]+).*\\b([0-9]+).[a-z]+$")

Comment: `\\.` is looking for the literal period `.`; in regex, a lone `.` means "any character". Anything. There are two ways to say we need the literal period: `\\.` and `[.]`, and there is no functional difference between the two. So the middle portion `\\b([0-9]+)\\.` is saying: a word-boundary followed by one or more digits followed by a period `.`".

Comment: It makes sense to me now. Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

another option:

```r
ord <- order(as.numeric(sub("(^\\d+)/.*$","\\1",files)), as.numeric(sub("^.*-(\\d+)\\.wav","\\1",files)))


files[ord]
#> [1] "3/Project_English-3/BL-0002_Lesser-horseshoe-bat/Fire-salamander-English-0067.wav"         
#> [2] "3/Project_English-3/BL-0002_Lesser-horseshoe-bat/Capercaillie-English-0069.wav"            
#> [3] "3/Project_English-3/BL-0002_Lesser-horseshoe-bat/Fat-tail-scorpion-English-0082.wav"       
#> [4] "10/Project_English-10/BL-0001_A-conifer-cone-contains-seeds/Birch-English-0700.wav"        
#> [5] "10/Project_English-10/BL-0001_A-conifer-cone-contains-seeds/Balsam-poplar-English-0701.wav"
#> [6] "10/Project_English-10/BL-0001_A-conifer-cone-contains-seeds/Blueberry-English-0703.wav"
```

Comment: It is also a good approach. In case someone like me who may not familiar with the regex, add some exp: ```\\d+ ``` is looking for the numeric characters in the string and "\\1" would select the character(s) in the first bracket(in this case it is number which match with ```\\d+ ```). Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A tidyverse solution: structuring data as a table and using `stringr::str_detect()` to arrange rows before extracting filenames.

```r
vec <- c( "10/Project_English-10/BL-0001_A-conifer-cone-contains-seeds/Balsam-poplar-English-0701.wav",
          "10/Project_English-10/BL-0001_A-conifer-cone-contains-seeds/Birch-English-0700.wav",
          "10/Project_English-10/BL-0001_A-conifer-cone-contains-seeds/Blueberry-English-0703.wav",
          "3/Project_English-3/BL-0002_Lesser-horseshoe-bat/Capercaillie-English-0069.wav",
          "3/Project_English-3/BL-0002_Lesser-horseshoe-bat/Fat-tail-scorpion-English-0082.wav",
          "3/Project_English-3/BL-0002_Lesser-horseshoe-bat/Fire-salamander-English-0067.wav")

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)


vec_tib <- tibble(filename = vec)

vec_tib <- mutate(vec_tib,
                  num_1 = str_extract(filename, "\\d+"),
                  num_2 = str_extract(filename, "\\d+(?=(\\.wav))"))

head(vec_tib, 3)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   filename                                                           num_1 num_2
#>   <chr>                                                              <chr> <chr>
#> 1 10/Project_English-10/BL-0001_A-conifer-cone-contains-seeds/Balsa… 10    0701 
#> 2 10/Project_English-10/BL-0001_A-conifer-cone-contains-seeds/Birch… 10    0700 
#> 3 10/Project_English-10/BL-0001_A-conifer-cone-contains-seeds/Blueb… 10    0703

vec_tib <- mutate(vec_tib, across(starts_with("num"), as.numeric))

vec_tib |> 
  arrange(num_1, num_2) |> 
  pull(filename)
#> [1] "3/Project_English-3/BL-0002_Lesser-horseshoe-bat/Fire-salamander-English-0067.wav"         
#> [2] "3/Project_English-3/BL-0002_Lesser-horseshoe-bat/Capercaillie-English-0069.wav"            
#> [3] "3/Project_English-3/BL-0002_Lesser-horseshoe-bat/Fat-tail-scorpion-English-0082.wav"       
#> [4] "10/Project_English-10/BL-0001_A-conifer-cone-contains-seeds/Birch-English-0700.wav"        
#> [5] "10/Project_English-10/BL-0001_A-conifer-cone-contains-seeds/Balsam-poplar-English-0701.wav"
#> [6] "10/Project_English-10/BL-0001_A-conifer-cone-contains-seeds/Blueberry-English-0703.wav"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>